# WIth Assembla or Unfuddle can I have a local version of my repositories and use that with VS 2012?

Tags: github, assembla, unfuddle

I've been developing alone and so have just used dropbox as a backup for copies of my MVC code that I develop with VS2012.

Now I have two more developers and I am looking for a way for the others to work with me. I was looking at Unfuddle and Assembla.  I've very very new to all this so please excuse this basic question.

With these two products can I have it so that my other two developers can fork copies of the code and have this on their local boxes and then do commits to add it to the code in the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for these platforms, for SCMs, which support local repositories (**not** for Subversion), forking repositories with cloning later forks to local repositories) and merge requests is one style of collaboration.

Another way is adding collaborators to the team of single shared central repo

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the repository you choose, with Assembla or Unfuddle git is offered and will allow you to do this.  SVN is also offered and will work as a backend repository, but it is not distributed and you cannot have a local repository.